# SqlCeEngine data types

Tags: c#, sql-server-ce

I wanna create table in database with column of type date. But I can't find the name of date type in SqlCeEngine.

I use this code:

```
SqlCeConnection connection = new SqlCeConnection(conString);
connection.Open();
cmd.CommandText = "CREATE TABLE Licenses (id int IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, start_date DATE_TYPE_HERE, end_date DATE_TYPE_HERE)";
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
connection.Close();
```

P.S. "date" doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is only one type for dates in SQL CE and it's `datetime`.

See [Data Types Supported in SQL Server CE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa275635%28v=sql.80%29.aspx).